# I am getting 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' .....when i tried to update a row in my table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to update a specific row in my table but i get An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

{"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."}

my action method is

```
 public ActionResult createedit()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32( Session["UserID"]);
        var Certtt = (from cert in db.TBL_UserRegistration where cert.UserLoginID == id select cert).FirstOrDefault();


        TBL_UserRegistration u = db.TBL_UserRegistration.Find(Certtt.UserRegistrationID);
        return View(u);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createedit(TBL_UserRegistration user, HttpPostedFileBase imageup)
    {



            if(imageup != null)
            {
                user.UserImage = new byte[imageup.ContentLength];
                imageup.InputStream.Read(user.UserImage, 0, imageup.ContentLength);
            }
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();


        return View(user);

    }
```

my view

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("createedit", "UserRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <form class="wiwet-checkout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />-->
                        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "text-label", @placeholder = "Password" })*@
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFirstName, "")
                    </div>
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

my model TBL_UserResgistration is

```
public partial class TBL_UserRegistration
{
    public TBL_UserRegistration()
    {
        this.TBL_Payment = new HashSet<TBL_Payment>();
    }

    public int UserRegistrationID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserRegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string UserCity { get; set; }
    public string UserState { get; set; }
    public string UserCountry { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserZip { get; set; }
    public string UserAddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string UserAdressLine2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UserPhone1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UserPhone2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserImage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserLoginID { get; set; }

    public virtual TBL_Login TBL_Login { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TBL_Payment> TBL_Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you add your TBL_UserRegistration  model ?

Comment: yes just a moment

Comment: @Munzer sir please take a look i just edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this exception because entity framework can't find your user object in the database to update it [READ MORE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx), that's because you are passing a user entity with only first name as I can see from your view, what you can do is this, pass your id as a hidden field, get user model by id from you database context, set the new user first name, update, done. 
this is how you do it

in your view, pass the id as hidden

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("createedit", "UserRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <!-- here is the hidden field keeping your id --> 
            @Html.Hidden("UserRegistrationID ",Model.UserRegistrationID )
            <form class="wiwet-checkout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />-->
                        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "text-label", @placeholder = "Password" })*@
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFirstName, "")
                    </div>
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

in your controller

```
// get the real entity from the database using the id passed to your controller
// as i mentioned before you should keep it in a hidden field 
TBL_UserRegistration u = db.TBL_UserRegistration.Find(user.UserRegistrationID);
// update the entity user name according to the new one passed from your view 
u.UserFirstName  = user.UserFirstName; 
// update    and save 
db.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: nothing changed in the controller ...any way thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great, Glad I helped